# How to use the Insert key to toggle `overwrite-mode` when using a PC keyboard in OS X?

Tags: osx, keystrokes, keyboard-layout

By default, when using a PC keyboard attached to a Mac, OS X treats presses of the  `Insert` key as presses of the `Help` key that appears on the extended Mac keyboard.

How do I map that keypress to have the same result in GNU Emacs that it does when running in, say, Windows or Linux: toggling `overwrite-mode` on and off?  (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Overwrite-mode.html)

In a GUI window, Emacs treats `Insert` presses as `Help` key presses and shows the help, which is logical.  Googling, I can't find anywhere that discusses remapping the `Help` key.

In OS X's Terminal.app, as far as I can tell, the key presses aren't passed to the terminal itself at all.  At a Bash prompt, `Ctrl-v Insert` results in no output.  Pressing another key behaves as if typing `Ctrl-v <key>` with no intervening press of `Insert`.

**EDIT**: I've gotten closer.  I think.

I used Karabiner [1] to map `Insert` to something more useful than `Help`, since Terminal.app doesn't see `Help`.  I picked `F13`.

[1] pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

```
<item>
    <name>Map Insert to F13</name>
    <identifier>private.map_insert_to_f13</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::PC_INSERT, KeyCode::F13</autogen>
</item>
```

`Ctrl+v Insert` in Bash then shows `^[[25~`.

Taking inspiration from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LinuxConsoleKeys I added the following to my .emacs:

```
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[25~" [(f13)])
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "<f13>") (kbd "<Insert>"))
```

Now pressing `Insert` once doesn't do anything.  Pressing it twice shows

```
<f1> <Insert> is undefined.
```

Pressing `Insert Down` shows

```
<f1> <down> is undefined.
```

I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

Placing the following snippet in `user-init-file` (`~/.emacs.d/init.el` in my case) worked for me. I also set ctrl-insert and shift-insert to copy/paste.

```el
(when (eq system-type 'darwin)
  ;; when using Windows keyboard on Mac, the insert key is mapped to <help>
  ;; copy ctrl-insert, paste shift-insert on windows keyboard
  (global-set-key [C-help] #'clipboard-kill-ring-save)
  (global-set-key [S-help] #'clipboard-yank)
  ;; insert to toggle `overwrite-mode'
  (global-set-key [help] #'overwrite-mode))
```

Comment: This answers the question for GUI Emacs - thanks.  But I still don't know how to solve this for console Emacs.